# Multiple read and write in a single pipe

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pipe, ipc

I am trying to understand pipes in Linux. Wrote a basic code which will try to write to writing end of the file descriptor twice and then perform read twice. On the second read it is blocking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int filedes[2];
    char buffer1[] = "hello pipe1";
    char buffer2[] = "hello pipe2";
    char readbuffer[30] = {};

    if (pipe(filedes) == 0) {
        printf("Pipe successful\n");
        printf("read from %d, write to %d\n", filedes[0], filedes[1]);
        write(filedes[1], buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
        perror("write");
        write(filedes[1], buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));
        perror("write");
        read(filedes[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("read:%s\n", readbuffer);
        read(filedes[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("read:%s\n", readbuffer);
        close(filedes[1]);
        close(filedes[0]);
    } else {
        perror("pipe failed");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get output as "hello pipe1" and then in the second read call it blocks
What happened to the second buffer data. Is it lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your readbuffer is 30 bytes, so this call:

```
read(filedes[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
```

will read up to 30 bytes.

You are writing 24 bytes (11 chars for each string plus 1 byte for the nul terminator).  The `read` will read all those bytes.  Nothing is lost.

The issue occurs here:

```
printf("read:%s\n", readbuffer);
```

readbuffer looks like this (where `\0` is the nul terminator):

```
hello pipe1\0hello pipe2\0
```

When printf hits the first nul, it treats that as the end of the string, so only "hello pipe1" will be printed.

If you change the readbuffer size to `sizeof(buffer1)`, this should work as expected (assuming both output strings are the same size).

Comment: While this has correctly diagnosed what IS happening, the recommendation is bad.  The real solution is to pay attention to the return value of system functions, in this case `read()`'s return value would have revealed the data following the NUL.

Answer (score 1):

The first `read` actually consumes all the data from both `write`s. The second call to `read` blocks because it didn't find any data available and is waiting for some to appear.

Why doesn't `printf()` display all of the data? Each call to `write()` sends a null terminator (`\0`). `printf`'s `s` specifier stops printing when it first encounters null.

To see this in detail, start by looking closely at the data in each buffer:

```c
char buffer1[] = "hello pipe1";
printf("strlen(buffer1): %zu\n", strlen(buffer1));
printf("sizeof(buffer1): %zu\n", sizeof(buffer1));
```

```
strlen(buffer1): 11
sizeof(buffer1): 12
```

The buffer actually contains:

```
hello pipe1\0
```

The compiler allocates 12 bytes: 11 bytes of text and 1 byte for the null terminator.

Checking the return value of [`write`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) show that it actually writes all 12 bytes:

```c
ssize_t n_written = write(filedes[1], buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
printf("Number of bytes written: %zd\n", n_written);
```

```
n_written: 12
```

It does this because `write`'s `count` argument tells it to:

```c
write(filedes[1], buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ write the entire buffer, including null
```

You can change this to write only the contents of the string:

```c
write(filedes[1], buffer1, strlen(buffer1));
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ write only the string's contents,
//                                         excluding null
```

but then you need to be *sure* that `readbuffer` is null terminated. Something like this is a start:

```c
ssize_t nread = read(filedes[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer)-1);
if (nread > 0)
    readbuffer[nread] = '\0';
```

Note that `read`'s `count` argument is saving space for the null terminator.